# How to search for an html tag and delete it

Tags: php, javascript, html, string, tags

I have made a description system, but all which doesn't work is my "search and delete unwanted tags"-system... Here's the code:

```
$mystring = $description;
$findme   = '<';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
echo $pos;

if ($pos == false) {
    $user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($user)) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE members SET description = '$description' WHERE username = '$myusername' AND password = '$mypassword'");
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><span style='color:#0076c9;'>Your description has successfully been changed! Go back to your page to see the changes!</span></td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><span style='color:#F00;'>Invalid input! Make sure that no other code than <br /> can be typed in!</span></td></tr>";
}
```

Is there any possible way of doing this? I have seen it on YouTube, but are too good! Anyone who knows how to do it?

Oh and I also noticed that my function only shows the position of the first tag... Not all tags and it can't see the difference between a `<br />` (which is allowed) and an `<img>` (not allowed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove HTML tags and only allow some of them 
you can use strip_tags function like this

```
strip_tags($text, '<br><a>');
```

This will return the text you entered $text with no tags except `<br> & <a>` tags 
You can read more about strip_tags [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: So <br> and <a> are the allowed tags? And all other tags are banned?

Comment: Yes exactly all the others are deleted

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)-function.

> string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

Example:

```
$str = "<a href='http://google.com'>Here</a> we go<br />";
echo strip_tags($str, "<br>");
```

Output: "Here we go <br />"

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add in more tags or just make it generic by taking out the section in parentheses:

```
if(preg_match("/<(span|html|table).*?>/", $description)) {
    rejected...
}
```

Comment: I think I may have minunderstood the first time around. If what you're looking for is not validation but removing tags then the answer @Kleist gave would probably be best.